# Dynamically changing label text upon events in another tkinter frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, dynamic, label, frames

I'm trying to dynamically change the text of a label within one frame from another frame. Both frames are within an instance of an object class.
This is not my actual problem but it illustrates the principle.
How can I address app.frame0.label1.text from app.frame1.button1.click?
(I appreciate that this is not the correct syntax)
Thank you in advance.

```py
from tkinter import *

txt = 'Hi'

def change():
    # idea was to put some code here to change frame0-label1-text
    pass

class HST(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        frame0 = Frame(self)
        frame0.grid(row=0, column=0)

        label1 = Label(frame0, text=txt, width=20, height=5)
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        button1 = Button(frame1, text='Click', width=20, height=5, command=change)
        button1.grid(row=0, column=1)

app = HST()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve my own problem! It is often helpful to lay out the issue to explain to someone else. Revised code using StringVar

```py
from tkinter import *

def change():
    app.txt.set('hello') # added
    pass

class HST(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.txt = StringVar() # added

        frame0 = Frame(self)
        frame0.grid(row=0, column=0)

        label1 = Label(frame0, textvariable=self.txt, width=20, height=5) # changed to use StringVar
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        button1 = Button(frame1, text='Click', width=20, height=5, command=change)
        button1.grid(row=0, column=1)

app = HST()
app.txt.set('Hi') # added to replace original line txt = 'Hi'
app.mainloop()
```